# Will this twitter feed stop working?

Tags: xml, twitter

We can get the twitter user data in XML format with following URL:

```
https://twitter.com/users/show/twitter
```

Will this also stop working when Twitter will shut down its API 1.0 ?
Is it safe to get data from this XML format? I could not find any information about this from twitter docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. What Server-Side language are you including?

If you are using PHP try [this](https://github.com/zkniebel/jquery-twitter-feed) (disregard the name - it has been updated to work with Twitter API 1.1), which has examples for making a request to Twitter's API 1.1 using PHP. It also has a jQuery plugin to help make rendering Tweets easier, and it is optimized for performance and robustness.

If you are using C#, you can still use the jQuery plugin from the above link to help you render your tweets, but use [this](https://github.com/zkniebel/TweetNet) for making your calls to Twitter. It is a library, named TweetNET, that is under continuous development and is regularly updated. Additionally, TweetNET is designed to mimic Twitter's API as closely as possible, so you should be able to follow along with Twitter's API and require little else for a reference. Nevertheless, TweetNET includes MSDN-style API documentation, as well as instructions.